# Spring MVC make view references type safe; or detect bad view names

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

@Controller handler methods are free to return any String that ostensibly represents a logical view name. Of course, the view name might be incorrect and the ViewResolver will fail to resolve it to an actual view.

Usually, all my views (e.g. .jsp files) are known on application startup, and all of my handler methods are hardcoded to return a view name (e.g. `return "home"` or `return "admin"`. Simple static analysis would detect an unresolvable returned view name from a handler method. Is there a way to build this safety into my application?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way for JSP is to extend *InternalResourceViewResolver* and override it's *buildView* method.

```
class BadViewDetectingViewResolver extends InternalResourceViewResolver {
    @Override
    protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
        final String absoluteViewName = getPrefix() + viewName + getSuffix();

        // Check if file exists or whatever you want.

        return super.buildView(viewName);
    }
}
```

Add this view resolver to your application context instead.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it would be difficult to do that simply because returned view name is logical name and the underlying view technology can be drastically different for e.g., jsp,velocity,thymeleaf etc. Spring ViewResolver actually resolves them depending upon for what technology it is configured. The view resolver too can be different for e.g., InternalResourceViewResolver, ResourceBundleViewResolver, ContentNegotiatingViewResolver etc. and these are called at runtime to resolve the view not when the application context is loaded.